# Displaying Picklist as radiobutton on VF

Tags: visualforce, picklist, radio-button

I have a picklist with values as yes and no. On my vf i need to display the same as radio buttons and while saving the values i need to save them as picklist values from th controller.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the dropdown to radio buttons with JavaScript also. First hide the dropdown, then take the data out of the  elements and create the `<input type="radio"/><label/><br/>` for each one. On click of the radio, you have to update the dropdown so that it will save the correct data.

This solution is based on this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029267/jquery-convert-select-to-radio-buttons).

```
<apex:page standardController="Book__c" >
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <apex:form id="myForm">
        <apex:inputField value="{!Book__c.Country__c}" id="picklistfield"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}" />
    </apex:form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Hide the picklist
        $('[id$=myForm] select').hide();
        //Get Exising Select Options    
        $('[id$=myForm] select').each(function(i, select){
            var $select = $(select);
            $select.find('option').each(function(j, option){
                var $option = $(option);
                // Create a radio:
                var $radio = $('<input type="radio" />');
                // Set name and value:
                $radio.attr('name', $select.attr('name')).attr('value', $option.val());
                // Set checked if the option was selected
                if ($option.attr('selected')) $radio.attr('checked', 'checked');
                // Insert radio before select box:
                $select.before($radio);
                // Insert a label:
                $select.before(
                    $("<label/>").attr('for', $select.attr('name')).text($option.text())
                );
                //Update the hidden picklist with selected radio value
                $radio.click(function () {
                    $('[id$=myForm] select').val($(this).val());
                })
                // Insert a <br />:
                $select.before("<br/>");
            });
        });            
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have an example here:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="accEx">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:selectRadio value="{!Account.Active__c}">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!Types}"></apex:selectOptions>
        </apex:selectRadio>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public class accEx {

    public accEx(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {    }

    public List<SelectOption> getTypes(){
        Schema.sObjectType sobject_type = Account.getSObjectType();
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sobject_describe = sobject_type.getDescribe();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> field_map = sobject_describe.fields.getMap();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> pick_list_values = field_map.get('Active__c').getDescribe().getPickListValues();
        List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>();
        for (Schema.PicklistEntry a : pick_list_values) {
                  options.add(new selectOption(a.getLabel(), a.getValue()));
        }
        return options;
    }
}
```

It was working fine.